# LiveReload on Rails 4.1.8 Not Working in Chrome or Safari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, livereload

I'm having a bear of a time setting up live reload. Perhaps someone else can see what I'm missing. First the error (from Chrome):

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:35729/livereload' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:35729/livereload' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
```

What I installed:

- Rails 4.1.8
- rack-livereload (0.3.15)
- rb-fsevent (0.9.4, 0.9.3)
- guard-livereload (2.4.0)

The changes I've made to my app that should enable this to work are:

```
# Gemfile
gem "guard", ">= 2.2.2",       :require => false
gem "guard-livereload",        :require => false
gem "rack-livereload"
gem "rb-fsevent",              :require => false

# development.rb
config.middleware.insert_after(ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::LiveReload)
```

I've tried this with `middleware.use` as well and still get the same error. I've checked to see whether there are other watchers on port 35729 and nothing obvious pops up.

Any pointers on how to get this working are appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your configuration looks correct. Here are some troubleshooting steps to take:

**Possibility 1: incompatible LiveReload versions**

Perhaps the version of `guard-livereload` (server) and `rack-livereload` (client) are incompatible. Upgrade both to the latest version to be safe:

```
bundle update guard-livereload rack-livereload
```

**Possibility 2: port 35729 is occupied**

Perhaps some other process is listening on port 35729, resulting in the connection errors you are seeing in Chrome. To check if this is the case, quit the guard process and then run:

```
netstat -an | grep 35729
```

If you see something like this, it means another process/app is listening on that port:

```
tcp4       0      0  *.35729                *.*                    LISTEN
```

You can try changing LiveReload to use a non-conflicting port. In the Guardfile, add the `:port` option, like this:

```
guard :livereload, :port => "56789" do
  ...
end
```

You'll also need to make a similar change in development.rb:

```
config.middleware.use(Rack::LiveReload, :live_reload_port => 56789)
```

**Possibility 3: misbehaving proxy**

The `ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED` error is [apparently](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=454311) a message Chrome gives when an HTTP proxy fails to forward a web socket request. If you have an HTTP proxy configured, this may be the problem.

To ensure that the proxy is not interfering with connections to your local LiveReload server, go to System Preferences → Network and select your active network adapter (e.g. WiFi, Ethernet). Then press Advanced and go to the Proxies tab. Make sure these entries are listed:

```
localhost
127.0.0.1
```

Comment: I did the bundle update, checked with `netstat` and no other listeners, and changed the port. Still not working. I disabled GlimmerBlocker and even then still not working. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, I'm stumped! Seems like a proxy issue, based on this search result: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=454311 .

Comment: You're spot on. I am running GlimmerBlocker, which proxies HTTP to port 8228. It gets rid of all those annoying Flash ads and stuff. What I did to fix, was to go into Network settings > Ethernet and add a `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` exclusion for the proxy. Would you please answer this so I can give you the credit?